# Timeline question?

Tags: flash, camera, platform

Im making a 2D game. Im new to Flash. 
If I make a new timeline layer, is it possiable in the actionscript to like call in everything in the timeleft?

Like if a make a new timeline layer and name it "Level", can i then do like this: 
if(Player.hitTestObject(Camera))
{
Level.y -= 1;
}

Like if the Player hits the camera, everything in the timeline layer "Level" should move 1?

Answer (score 0):

No that cannot be done. It isn't too hard to stick all the objects into an array and loop through that array to move all the objects, but you can't manipulate timeline layers directly like that. Many elements from the Flash editor are exposed in code but not everything: code can manipulate MovieClips and Buttons; not plain vectors, not Graphic objects, and not layers.